# How to concatenate elements into an array?

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, jq

I have a file containing structured log lines like so:

```
{"generation_id":13,"level":"info","member_id":"sarama-78cdf4cb-ce00-4a67-8b3a-b2bc46c6abb1","msg":"starting consumer","time":"2019-08-28T18:24:46.303Z"}
{"generation_id":13,"initial_offset":178921,"level":"info","member_id":"sarama-78cdf4cb-ce00-4a67-8b3a-b2bc46c6abb1","msg":"starting to consume from partition","partition":18,"time":"2019-08-28T18:24:46.304Z"}
{"generation_id":13,"initial_offset":-1,"level":"info","member_id":"sarama-78cdf4cb-ce00-4a67-8b3a-b2bc46c6abb1","msg":"starting to consume from partition","partition":19,"time":"2019-08-28T18:24:46.305Z"}
```

I'd like to sort them by `.time`. How can I do it with `jq`?

I've tried:

```
jq '. | sort_by(.time)' < log.log
```

and

```
jq '. |= sort_by(.time)' < log.log
```

but I keep getting:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:15630): Cannot index string with string "time"
jq: error (at <stdin>:15631): Cannot index string with string "time"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are separate entities, you need to slurp them first to make sorting possible, then you can undo the slurping to get the same look as the original input. Like:

```
jq -cs 'sort_by(.time)[]' log.log
```